Puppeteer can't find Chrome installation on Ubuntu if called from a Laravel Process
I'm trying to get Laravel to run a Puppeteer script in an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS EC2 machine. It is defined as "puppeteer": "^22.10.0" in my package.json and it was successfully installed in /home/ubuntu/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-125.0.6422.78/chrome-linux64:

When i run a test script directly in the server with node puppetter-test.js, it seem to work. The script is:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const testUrl = 'https://pptr.dev/';

(async () => {
    try {
        const logContent = JSON.stringify({
            env: process.env,
            params: process.argv,
            puppeteer: puppeteer.default.configuration
        });

        console.log(`Puppeteer Node Debug: ${logContent}`);

        // Instantiate puppeteer
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            headless: true,
            logLevel: 'error'
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Puppeteer launch() error: ' + error);
        });

        console.log('> Browser initiated.');

        // Instantiate browser
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(testUrl,
        {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
            timeout: 0
        });

        console.log('> Page loaded');
    }
    catch (e) {
        throw 'Puppeteer test error(1): ' + e.toString();
    }

    process.exit(0);
})();

It prints without errors:
> Browser initiated.
> Page loaded

But when I run it from Laravel with the following code:
$result = Process::path($cmdPath) // $cmdPath is the path to the app root where node is installed
    ->timeout(120)
    ->run($cmd, function($output) { // $cmd is the node script call
        CloudLogHelper::log('Puppeteer internal log: ' . $output);
    });

The script throws this exception:

Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 125.0.6422.78). This can occur if either
1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/ubuntu/.cache/puppeteer).

As you can see, I had installed chrome with npx puppeteer browsers install chrome and it is located on the right cache path with 755 permissions to the chrome executable.
This code works in a local development machine(Windows) and works in a Heroku host. It just doesn't works in an EC2 Ubuntu machine.
Any advise on this ?

Possibly related? Could not find Chrome (ver. 127.0.6533.72). puppeteer

@ggorlen I dont know, but I did what the answer in that question suggested.

Did it work for you?

@ggorlen it didn't
